# Is this circular motion answer wrong?

Tags: solution-verification, physics, classical-mechanics

I was doing a few very old circular motion questions and came across a question where I believe the answer is incorrect.  The book's answer is $ 18.88 \; N$, whereas I get $19.68\;N$. Can someone verify my solution is correct (or incorrect!).

*One end of a light inelastic string of length $2\;m$ is attached to a fix point $2.5 \;m$ vertically above the centre of a fixed sphere of radius $1.5\;m$.  A small ball, of mass $2\;kg$, at the other end of the string is made to rotate in a horizontal circle on the smooth surface of the sphere with a speed of $2\;m/s$.  Show the string must be taut and calculate the tension in it.*

Below is my diagram showing the current situation.

[image]

The string must be taught since it makes a right angle triangle $1.5 : 2: 2.5$ or $3 : 4 : 5$.  Using this I can find $\sin \theta = \frac{3}{5}$ and $\cos \theta = \frac{4}{5}$.  I can also find the value of $r$, which I will need when calculating the the circular motion force.  To find $r$, using the smaller right angled triangle.

$$ \sin \theta = \frac{r}{2} $$
$$ \frac{3}{5} = \frac{r}{2} $$
$$ r = \frac{6}{5} $$

$\vec{j} $ components:
$$ T \cos \theta + N \sin\theta = 2g $$
$$ T \cdot \frac{4}{5} + N \cdot \frac{3}{5} = 2g $$
$$ 4T + 3N = 10g \label{eq:EQU1} \tag{1} $$

$\vec{i} $ components $F = ma$:
$$ T \sin \theta - N \cos \theta = \frac{mv^2}{r} $$
$$ T \cdot \frac{3}{5} - N \cdot \frac{4}{5} = \frac{2 \cdot 2^2}{\frac{6}{5}} $$
$$ T \cdot \frac{3}{5} - N \cdot \frac{4}{5} = \frac{20}{3} $$
$$ 3T - 4N = \frac{100}{3}  $$
$$ 9T - 12N = 100 \label{eq:EQU2} \tag{2} $$

Eliminate $N$ by  $ (1) \times 4 + (2) $

$$ 25T = 40g + 100 $$
$$ T = 19.68 $$

The book's answer is $ 18.88\;N$.  If someone can point out my error it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that the question and your answer use different values for $g$? Possible values are 9.8, 9.81, $\pi^2$, 10

Comment: I don't think so Lutz.... But do you think my logic is correct?

Comment: In principle your approach is correct. But quick check, $N$ has to be negative for the small ball to remain on the sphere, this seems not to be the case here? Anyway, any sign corrections would lead to drastically different results, so that is not likely with the relatively small difference. Calculating the reference solution backwards gives $g=9.3$ for $T=18.88$. Thus there could have been a typo or reading error in calculating the reference solution, mistaking the $8$ for a $3$.

Comment: I have found a few typos in the latter chapters of this very old book... so it is possible.  Thank-you so much for your effort.